# Calling method by name Delphi 10 Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, call, firemonkey, procedure, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to call methods by name in a firemonkey project. But so far no luck.

Below is my code:

```
type
  TExecute = procedure of object;
  TUpdates= class(TDataModule)
     procedure UpdateToVersion(Version: Integer);
  private
     procedure UpdateToVersion1;
     procedure UpdateToVersion2;
     procedure UpdateToVersion3;
     procedure Call(Name: string);
  public
  end;

procedure TUpdates.Call(Name: String);
var
  m:TMethod;
  Exe:TExecute;
begin
  m.Data := pointer(Self);
  m.Code := Self.MethodAddress(Name);
  Exe := TExecute(m);
  Exe;
end;

procedure TUpdates.UpdateToVersion(Version: Integer);
begin
   Call('UpdateToVersion'+version.ToString);
end;

procedure TUpdates.UpdateToVersion1;
begin
   //code
end;

procedure TUpdates.UpdateToVersion2;
begin
   //code
end;

procedure TUpdates.UpdateToVersion3;
begin
   //code
end;
```

**Results:**
When I call for example UpdateToVersion(1) I get an access violation and procedure UpdateToVersion1 doesn't get called.

I got this code from an example from the link below:
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MethodAddress` requires that the method is published, as is the method in the example code. Your methods are private. Hence `MethodAddress` fails and returns `nil`.

Solve the problem by publishing the methods.

If you wish to perform this sort of task with non-published methods then you will need to use enhanced RTTI.